# How to remove empty span elements in HTML dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js to bind span elements as shown below, how to hide lane 2 if it is empty ? There will be multiple addresses so I can't keep a id and hide. Thanks in advance.

```
<span data-bind="text:lane1"></span><br>
<span data-bind="text:lane2"></span><br>
<span data-bind="text:city"></span><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [visible binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html)

```
<span data-bind="text:lane1"></span><br>
<span data-bind="text:lane2"></span><br data-bind="visible: lane2">
<span data-bind="text:city"></span><br>
```

But would it not be easier to use div instead of span if you want linebreaks ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now knockout.js is generating            <span data-bind="text:lane2 , visible: lane2" style="display: none;"></span> but still empty line is being displayed. Can you me ?

Comment: I didn't see the br elements... you can move the visible binding in the br element so that it is hidden if lane2 if empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd be willing to use CSS (and risk the cross-browser compatibility problems that may present), you can use CSS attribute-selection and the `:empty` pseudo-class:

```
span[data-bind="text:lane2"]:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

The above assumes you want to hide the `span` with that `data-bind` value; if you simply want to hide all `span` elements with a `data-bind` attribute, that are empty:

```
span[data-bind]:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

Note that the `:empty` pseudo-class requires that the element be completely empty (no child elements or even text-nodes at all).

References:

- [Attribute presence and selection](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-representation).
- [`:empty` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#empty-pseudo).